# slideToggle with slideUp

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, slideup

I have posted my CV on my website, and I've got the different sections of it hidden when the page loads. I used slideToggle to allow the user to click on each section to open or close it. That part was working great. But I also wanted the user to have the option to just open or close all sections at once, instead of having to scroll down the page opening or closing each section one by one. So I created a "Show All" option at the top of the page. Once I tried to get that to work, things got wonky. Here is my HTML (just a sample), CSS, and JQuery:

```
<div class="toggle">
        <h2><span class="toggleIcon">[+]</span> Education</h2>
            <p>Ph.D. in English, Duke University, 2009-present<p>
            <p class="indent">Certificate in College Teaching</p>
            <p class="indent">Certificate in Feminist Studies</p>
            <p>M.A. in English, Brooklyn College, CUNY, 2008</p>
            <p>B.A. in English and Anthropology, University of Texas, Austin, 2005</p>
    </div>

<div class="toggle">
        <h2><span class="toggleIcon">[+]</span> Publications</h2>
            <h3>Journal Articles</h3>
                <p class="indent">"'After' Theory," in <span>Theory@Buffalo: Conditions of Possibility</span> 13 (2009). Print.</p>
            <h3>Book Chapters</h3>
                <p class="indent">"'I do not want the judgment of any man': The Unstable Animal-Human Boundary in Linguistics and Kafka's 'A Report to an Academy,'' in <span>Of Mice and Men: Animals in Human Culture</span>. Newcastle upon Tyne: Cambridge Scholars Press, 2009. 81-91. Print.</p>
            <h3>Other</h3>
                <p class="indent">Rev. of <span>Chang and Eng Reconnected: The Original Siamese Twins in American Culture</span>, by Cynthia Wu, <span>Imperfect Unions: Staging Miscegenation in U.S. Drama and Fiction</span>, by Diana Rebekkah Paulin, and <span>Racial Indigestion: Eating Bodies in the 19th Century</span>, by Kyla Wazana Tompkins, in <span>American Literature</span> 86.2 (2014): 394-396. Print.</p>
    </div>

#options {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -25px;
}

#toggleAllIcon {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.toggle p, .toggle h3 {
    display: none;
}

$(function() {
    $(".toggleIcon").click(function() { //when user clicks icon
        $(this).parent().parent().children("h3, p").slideToggle(); //content slides down or up
        });
    });


$(function() {
    $("#toggleAllIcon").click(function() {
        if ( 
            $(".toggle h3, .toggle p").is(":visible")
            ) {
                $(".toggle h3, .toggle p").slideUp(function() {
                    $(".toggle h3, toggle p").slideToggle();
            });
        } else {
            $(".toggle h3, .toggle p").slideToggle();
        };
    });
});
```

A lot of people working with these menus only want one section to be visible at a time. Just to clarify, that isn't my issue. I want users to be able to have multiple sections open at once if they want. I just also want them to have the option to control all sections at the same time. With my original code, when I clicked the "#toggleAllIcon", it would control the entire document, but if a user already had a section open, that section would close and the other sections would open. I want it to work so that when you click that icon, ALL sections either open together or close together. I also tried calling stop after slideUp but that just shut all my code down.

You can see what happens with the above code: http://www.clare-eileen-callahan.com/ The page starts to dance. It's obviously confused. I also imagine there is not just a correct way but a much more efficient way to achieve the effect I want. Help appreciated!

Comment: What is this if statement? `if ( 
            $(".toggle h3, .toggle p").is(":visible")
            ) {
                $(".toggle h3, .toggle p").slideUp(function() {
                    $(".toggle h3, toggle p").slideToggle();
            });`

Comment: also i'm not sure it's wise to post such personal information on here, but i don't know if SO has any policies about this or not.

Comment: To toggle all why don't you just trigger `click` on the `.toggleIcon` elements since you've already set that event up?

Comment: *"I want it to work so that when you click that icon, ALL sections are either open or closed"* To satisfy this statement you can create a button that does nothing. Can you rephrase? EDIT: Oh you mean, ShowAll and HideAll, not ToggleAll.

Comment: Popnoodles, so that all sections open or close at the same time when you click on the show all icon. DLeh, the if statement was an attempt to have all sections slide back up again before calling slideToggle so that all sections would open or close at the same time, rather than have some open and others closed. Also, this is all public information - it's up on my website.

Comment: Use `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` and set something to remember which action it last used, and if they are all inverted by the user, invert that setting to avoid a null click.

Comment: Popnoodles, exactly, but I was wanting to work with toggle because I want the "Show All" button to alternate between hiding and showing all sections at once. Once I get this code right, I'm going to ask the text to toggle from "Show" to "Hide," but I'm trying to take one step at a time. Will try .slideUp(). I was using it previously but it wasn't working, so I'll have to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it would be much easier if you differentiate between when the toggle should "Show All" or "Hide All". I suggest using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to determine what the toggle should do (slideUp all or slideDown all)

```
$(function() {
    $("#toggleAllIcon").click(function() {
      $("#toggleAllIcon").toggleClass('show-all');

      if($("#toggleAllIcon").hasClass('show-all')) {
        $(".toggle h3, .toggle p").slideDown();
      } 
      else {
        $(".toggle h3, .toggle p").slideUp();
      }
    });
});
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dCmak

Hope that helps a bit. One scenario you might want to consider is what happens if the user has individually expanded all sections already when they click "Show All"? And vice versa with "Hide All".

Comment: Worked great. Would I be able to write an } if else () statement in there to account for whether the user has already individually expanded all sections?

Comment: Yes, I would start by looking at your original if statement - `if ($(".toggle h3, .toggle p").is(":visible"))` - should return false if everything is hidden I would have thought? Haven't tested.